# Problema al modificar cadena de conexión

Tags: vb.net

Estoy haciendo un código en Visual Studio, y estoy tratando de modificar una cadena de conexión a una base de Access, pero cuando hago el cambio me arroja el mensaje:

> El formato de la cadena de inicialización no se ajusta a la especificación que comienza en el índice 34.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
cadenaconex = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & TextBox1.Text
```

Donde `textbox1.text` es la ubicación del archivo de base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas lurduy,

Tienes un error de sintaxis en el código que nos muestras:

```
cadenaconex = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & TextBox1.Text
```

Si te fijas, has puesto una comilla simple `'` antes de cerrar las comillas dobles `"`, pero no vuelves a poner la comilla simple para cerrar.

En tu caso las comillas simples no son necesarias para poner la ruta de la BD, así que debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
cadenaconex = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: Gracias, era eso, muchas gracias por tu ayuda